# How to unzip tar.gz file with Rust?

Tags: rust, compression, gzip, unzip

I'm building a cli tool that unzips a file (probably tar.gz) and then move it to a target directory using the zip_extract crate. But I got stuck. I don't really understand much yet about compression neither Rust.

**Code**

```
#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    zip_path: std::path::PathBuf
}


fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>{

    let args = Cli::parse();

    let default_path = Path::new("/home/hal/jetbrains");

    let file = File::open(&args.zip_path)?;
    match zip_extract::extract(file, default_path, true){
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(err) => panic!("Error {}", err)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**Error**

- invalid Zip archive: Could not find central directory end

**Tries**

I figured the problem could be about which format zip_extract crate accepts.
I made sure to pass a valid compressed file path, and even used different files with different compressed formats.
First I used a .tar.gz, which gave me this error, then I've tried passing a .bz2, which gave me the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"invalid Zip archive:"* - .tar.gz is not a ZIP archive. It is a tar archive compressed with gzip. See https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-cookbook/blob/master/src/compression/tar/tar-decompress.md how to handle these.

Comment: Yeah, precisely, solved my problem, though I still wonder why it didn't work for .bz2.

Comment: *"it didn't work for .bz2"* - Because .bz2 is yet another compression format (bzip2), different from gzip.  See https://docs.rs/bzip2/latest/bzip2/. Welcome in the wonderful world of zillions of archive and compression formats :)

Comment: hahaha fair enough. I believe I misunderstood that zip_extract supported bzip2 (https://docs.rs/zip-extract/latest/zip_extract/), thanks !